# Grid blowout vertically from parent container with fixed height

Tags: css

Lets suppose I have parent container with fixed height:

```css
.container {
   max-height: 100px;
}
```

This container contains a grid, which has to be take the whole height, and if cell's content doesn't fit, it has to be scrollable.

```css
.grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
   grid-template-rows: minmax(1px, 1fr) minmax(1px, 1fr);
}
```

But if content of grid's cells is too big vertically, the grid is blowout the parent container, and I have no idea how to fix it.

`minmax` doesn't work for me in this case.

**Example code:**

```css
.container {
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(1px, 1fr) minmax(1px, 1fr);
}

.grid>* {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.grid .left {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.grid .right-top {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.grid .right-bottom {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="left">
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-top">
      Right Top Content
    </div>

    <div class="right-bottom">
      Right Bottom Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because I want each cell is scrollable, obviously. I don't want to scroll the whole grid

Comment: I know what you mean by now, please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `max-height: inherit;` to the `.grid` so it can inherit the max height to make the overflow works properly.

Ultimately you want to restrict height of the `.grid` instead of the container, since it's the children of the `.grid` needs to be scrollable, not `.container`.

```css
.container {
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(1px, 1fr) minmax(1px, 1fr);
  
  /* added */
  max-height: inherit;
}
.grid > * {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.grid .left {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1/span 2;
}
.grid .right-top {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.grid .right-bottom {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="left">
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="right-top">
      Right Top Content<br>
      Right Top Content<br>
      Right Top Content<br>
      Right Top Content<br>
      Right Top Content<br>
      Right Top Content<br>
      Right Top Content<br>
    </div>
    
    <div class="right-bottom">
      Right Bottom Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the parent a flexbox container

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  max-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  width:100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(1px, 1fr) minmax(1px, 1fr);
}

.grid>* {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.left {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.right-top {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.right-bottom {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="left">
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
      <div>Left Content </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-top">
      Right Top Content
    </div>

    <div class="right-bottom">
      Right Bottom Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe your answer could analyze the problem and explain how making the parent a flexbox container solves it?